# Accordion is failing accessibility check

Tags: testing, accessibility, accordion

I have an accordion that is rendered using [van11y-accessible-accordion-aria](https://github.com/nico3333fr/van11y-accessible-accordion-aria)

The markup outputs as:

```html
<div className="c-accordion__items js-accordion accordion" data-accordion-cool-selectors="1" aria-multiselectable="true" role="tablist" id="z3j2diubs8r" data-hashaccordion-id="3o3nlqickh">
   <!-- note role="tablist" above -->
   <div className="c-accordion__item">
      <h2 className="c-accordion__title accordion__title">
         <button className="js-accordion__header accordion__header" role="tab" id="accordionz3j2diubs8r_tab1" aria-controls="accordionz3j2diubs8r_panel1" aria-selected="false" type="button" data-hashaccordion-id="3o3nlqickh" aria-expanded="false">
            <!-- note role="tab" above -->
            The Why
         </button>
      </h2>
      <div className="c-accordion__item-components js-accordion__panel accordion__panel" role="tabpanel"
         aria-labelledby="accordionz3j2diubs8r_tab1" id="accordionz3j2diubs8r_panel1" data-hashaccordion-id="3o3nlqickh"
         aria-hidden="true">
         <div className="c-accordion__item-content">
            <p>Duis vel nibh at velit scelerisque suscipit. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Quisque ut
               nisi. Ut non enim eleifend felis pretium feugiat. Nulla sit amet est.
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

When I test this for accessibility using Lighthouse in Chrome, I am getting these messages

> Elements with an ARIA [role] that require children to contain a specific [role] are missing some or all of those required children.
> Some ARIA parent roles must contain specific child roles to perform their intended accessibility functions. Learn more.

> [role]s are not contained by their required parent element
> Some ARIA child roles must be contained by specific parent roles to properly perform their intended accessibility functions. Learn more.

The learn more links goes to https://web.dev/aria-required-children and shown below is a code example that they suggest.

[image]

... and there it implies that having `role="tablist"` as the parent and then `role="tab"` for the child.

In my code posted in this question, I seem to have the proper markup as compared to the example from https://web.dev/aria-required-children

So I am at a loss as to why this is failing the accessibility check.

Comment: Lighthouse gives somewhat questionable results. Have you tried a browser plugin like Axe or SiteImprove? Check the code here provided by W3C: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/accordion/accordion.html. Your example is for tabs, not accordions, so doesn't apply.

Comment: @NathanielFlick Lighthouse has used Axe core for at least 2 years now so the results are normally valid.  It used to be a massive issue but nowadays if Lighthouse says there is an issue then Axe will say the same (which it does).

Comment: Have you tried SiteImprove? It also gives good results and might be a good test. Some Axe core tests are turned off: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/7510

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`role="tab"` must be a direct descendant (or contained within an element with no semantic meaning) of a `role="tablist"` element. To be fair this is really not clear in the WAI-ARIA spec but I have hit this issue myself before. (you can use [`aria-owns`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-owns) to make the association but that is more for if the tabs sit outside the `tablist` element)

Because your `<button>` is wrapped in a `<h2>` this breaks the pattern.

I have tested it and it appears to work in JAWS and NVDA, but just to be safe (as there are loads of screen readers and some of them may not like your implementation) I would make a minor adjustment.

Remove the `<h2>` that surrounds the `<button>` is one option and probably the one I would recommend. It doesn't make much sense to have multiple `<h2>` elements on a widget anyway and instead you should use a heading above the tabs you have created for the section.

A second option is to make the `<h2>` function like a button, but that would mean adding your own event handlers, focus indicators and `tabindex="0"` to make it focusable. That way you can move the `role="tab"` onto the `<h2>` itself, which removes the semantic meaning but retains the ability to navigate to it in a screen reader.

I personally am not a fan of the second option but I can see why some people may choose to do that.

One other thing I would suggest is to put the `tabs` and the `tabpanel`s inside `<ul>` and `<li>`.

For screen readers that don't support `tablist` this means a user still gets an announcement of "1 out of 3 options" etc. So it makes it easier to understand they have options.

Also it is recommended that each `tabpanel` has a `tabindex="0"` to aid navigation once a tab has been selected. This is one of those very rare circumstances where making a non-interactive element focusable is encouraged.

You may find [this W3 page on tab best practices](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/tabs/tabs-2/tabs.html) useful.

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer, I really appreciate that. I have a much better picture now of what I need to do.

Comment: Not an issue at all, glad it helped! Good luck with the project!

Comment: *"role="tab" must be a direct descendant"*.  That's not quite accurate. The [tab spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#tab) says *"Authors MUST ensure elements with role tab are **contained in**, or owned by, an element with the role tablist."*  **"Contained in"** does not mean a "direct descendant". That is, as long as it's somewhere down the ancestor chain, then it's valid. It doesn't have to be an immediate child. Wrapping a button in an h2 is ok.